# How to select keyboard input file for Add Input Source

Tags: keyboard, input-source

Here is the dialog for adding an input source.  Nowhere does a "choose file" file chooser dialog button appear.

[image]

Then hitting Add (+):

[image]

And there is NO Choose File dialog here either.

So then what is the correct process?

Comment: Why are you looking for Choose File?  You just select the layout you want on the right and click on add.

Comment: @TomGewecke  No, the "My Layout" is grayed out - disabled.

Comment: You need to tell us what you made your layout with and where you installed it exactly.  Do you have permission to access where you put your .keylayout file?  A  good place to ask for help with Ukelele is at  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Comment: I found the problem.  See my answer. This was quite non obvious/simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying confusion here is that an existing keyboard layout file may not be modified in place.  You need to delete it or rename it then add it back.

The Input Sources program actually reads the xml's of the files uner

```
~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/
```

It will not allow you to re-select a layout with the same name of one it already knows about.  Unfortunately that prevents updating an existing one using the existing name.

You have to update the layout name in the xml:

```
<keyboard group="0" id="5000" name="Dollar Layout" maxout="1">
    <layouts>
```